# Concatenating a string to an existing string in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting some data into my database, such as deductedwh and note. And i have an update function that i'm using based on $sql2. The thing is, that deductedwh is a number and it's successfully being added with the previous value in the column.
However when it comes to note (text) I'm trying to append the new text value ($note) to the previous existing text in the column (Note). But it's not working, most likely my syntax is wrong. Any guidance please?

```
 $sql2 = "UPDATE editedworkhours SET DeductedWH = DeductedWH +'$deductedhours' AND Note = Note . '$note' WHERE AFNumber='$selectaf'";
            $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

            if (isset($result2))
            {

            }
            else
            {

                echo '<script>swal("Error", "Something went wrong error");</script>';
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mysql **concat**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm) function:

```
UPDATE
    editedworkhours
SET
    DeductedWH = DeductedWH + CAST('$deductedhours' AS UNSIGNED),
    Note = CONCAT(Note,'$note')
WHERE
    AFNumber ='$selectaf';
```

Comment: thanks i'll accept the answer in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `concat()` to concatenate your new text with your existing text also you have typo a in `set` replace and with comma

```
"UPDATE editedworkhours 
SET DeductedWH = DeductedWH +'$deductedhours' 
,Note = concat(Note, '$note')
WHERE AFNumber='$selectaf'";
```

Answer (score 0):

To update multiple columns in Mysql you have to use comma as separator not AND

```
SET DeductedWH = DeductedWH +'$deductedhours' , Note = concat(Note, . '$note'.)
```